# how to do a loop every time it hits a blank and insert a sum formula of rows above?

Tags: excel, vba

I'm having issues creating the loop of which I can do the sum of the "delivery qty" in the yellow spot below each section.

What I'm trying to do is loop through the whole form and do the sum of the "delivery qty" and insert it into the yellow blank space that I have inserted after each Supplier Do No.

[image: question]

```
Sub SumOfDeliveryQty()
    Dim ws As Excel.Worksheet
    Dim lRow As Long
    Dim lStartSection As Long

    Set ws = Application.Sheets("PO Copy")
    lRow = 2
    lStartSection = 0

    'Loop through the used range in the spreadsheet
    Do While lRow <= ws.UsedRange.Rows.Count

        'If we are at the start of a section record the row.
        If lStartSection = 0 And ws.Range("F" & lRow).Value <> "" Then
            lStartSection = lRow
        End If

        'Check if we are at the bottom of a section
        If ws.Range("F" & lRow).Value = "Total" Then
            ws.Range("F" & lRow).Value = "=SUM(F" & lStartSection & ":F" & lRow - 1 & ")"

            'Set this back to zero so we know that we are no longer in a section
            lStartSection = 0
        End If

    lRow = lRow + 1
    Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: If you show the code that you are having issues with, we may be able to help you.  Without seeing the code, all we can do is make wild guesses as to what you are doing wrong.

Comment: i was actually following an example which i found but that wasn't working as well.

Comment: You don't seem to have any "Total" values in column F, so it doesn't seem to make much sense using that as your test to see whether to apply the total on that row.  Perhaps use `If ws.Range("C" & lRow).Value = "" Then`?  (I am assuming column C is the first column in your posted screenshot based on the fact that the code you are using is totalling column F - adjust the "C" if that isn't correct.)

Comment: Ah! cool understand. i forgot to change that clause.. was wondering why it wasn't working. thanks a lot!